# How do i open adobe reader from vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I created an application which will be able to open a pdf file but what i want is to be able to open a pdf file with Adobe Reader from Vb with just a button click
here is the code used so far

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF Files | *.pdf"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

        AxAcroPDF1.src = OpenFileDialog1.FileName


    End If


End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You can simply call `Process.Start` and pass the path of a data file to open that file in its default application. If you do that then it will open Adobe Reader for those people who use it and open some other application for those who don't. For instance, I use Microsoft Edge as my default PDF reader and don't have Adobe Reader installed at all.

Comment: Please am sorry, i don't know how to do that.. thank you

Comment: All the above answers says is that you can write `Process.Start(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)`, and the PDF file will be opened on the user's PDF viewer, whichever that is.

Comment: Thank you its worked like cham.....

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to import `System.Diagnostics` namespace or use directly

```
Diagnostics.Process.Start("fullpathtofiletoexecute")
```